# GAE index size and entries unknown

Tags: python, google-app-engine

[image: Screenshot from GAE admin console]

I have set up the index in GAE correctly, but what does the '-' mean in size and entries?

Answer (score 0):

All metadata is not updated in real time:

> Reading metadata using the API gets current data, whereas data in the
>   dashboard is updated only once daily.

I think it applies to index data too. You will most likely see the updated information tomorrow.